Install MongoDB on a drive other than C
During the installation of MongoDB Community 7.0 the installer asks for the paths to the DB, and I point them at the dedicated, 50GB empty drive E:, which was created specially for MongoDB.
The next step says that the target drive C: does not have enough space. And the list of drives below shows C: and E:, but E: is unselectable.
Can MongoDB not be installed on any drives other than C:?

This has been asked and answered on another SE site, in slightly different terms: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68491934/mongodb-doesnt-install-on-the-preferred-installation-disk-windows
The answers very kindly refer to the root cause as "100 IQ development" whereas it would be more accurately described as "0-IQ development".
Bottom line is that the installer is too dumb and makes stupid assumptions, whereas it only needs to copy a few files. The 2 workarounds are to use a portable ZIP to install or to unpack the MSI and extract the actual MSI that installs the server.
If you have no choice other than to use that thing, use one of them.

The portable ZIP is a working alternative. The only thing to keep an eye on is 1+ GB of debug symbols that they include, and not to extract them. You are spot-on re their IQ.

To install MongoDB on a drive other than the C drive, such as the D drive, you'll need to follow these steps:
1. Run Installer with "Custom" setup type
Double-click the MongoDB installer (.msi file) you downloaded.
Choose Setup Type: When you reach the "Setup Type" screen, select "Custom".
2. Customize Installation Path
Select Destination Location: You'll see an option to choose the installation path. Click "Change" and select the desired location on the D drive. For example, you might choose D:\MongoDB.
Complete the Installation: Proceed with the installation process by following the prompts.
Also change directory to "D drive" for "log" and "data" storage, when asked in prompt.
Voila! your mongoDB will be installed in D Drive.
